# Microsoft Band does not receive text message or e-mail notifications

Tags: push-notifications, microsoft-band

**Question:**

My Windows phone does not send text message or e-mail notifications to the Microsoft Band. However, it does notify me of incoming and missed calls. Can anyone help me identify which Phone setting is preventing me from receiving text and e-mail notifications on the Band?

**Details:**

- Nokia Lumia 735 with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 and Microsoft Health 1.3.10720.1 installed
- Microsoft Band with Build Version 10.3.3304.0 09 R
- Data is intentionally disabled on the phone and wi-fi is unavailable
- The phone and the band both indicate that the devices are paired
- In the Microsoft Health application, I have ensured "Manage Tiles" > "Messaging" > "Enable text message notifications on your Band." is turned on
- In the Microsoft Health application, I have ensured "Manage Tiles" > "Mail" > "Enable mail notifications on your Band." is turned on

Comment: Windows Phone 8.2 doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the "Battery Saver" app (if you have it installed) is set to allow the Microsoft Health app to run in the background. Otherwise, the text message and e-mail notifications will not go through to the Microsoft Band.